# Doesn't statement 'S is a set of all sets that are not elements of themselves.' hold true by reductio ad absurdum?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> The simplest of the logical paradoxes is *Russell's paradox*, which can be described as follows:
>
> Let $S$ denote the *set of all sets that are not elements of themselves*. Is $S$ an element of itself?
>
> - Well, if $S$ is an element of $S$, then - by the very definition of $S$ - $S$ is not an element of $S$.
> - If $S$ is not an element of $S$, then (again, because of the way $S$ is defined) $S$ is an element of $S$.
>
> Thus, we have proven that $S$ is an element of $S$ if and only if $S$ is not an element of $S$ - a contradiction of the most fundamental sort.
>
> Source: Set Theory by Charles C. Pinter, p.5 [Formatting not withstanding].

From the above explanation, reductio ad absurdum can be applied to the statement '**$S$ is a set of all sets that are not elements of themselves**.'as follows:
$$\begin{align}
S \in S &\Rightarrow S \notin S\\
&\Rightarrow S\in S\\
&\therefore S\in S \Leftrightarrow S\notin S 
\end{align}$$

Since the statement leads to a contradictin, $\color{purple}{ S\in S \Leftrightarrow S\notin S}$, doesn't the statement '**$S$ is a set of all sets that are not elements of themselves**.' hold true?

[Edit Ahh. I'm starting to understand it a bit more]

The quote "Let $S$ denote the *set of all sets that are not elements of themselves*. Is $S$ an element of itself?" can be rephrased as 'If S denote the *set of all sets that are not elements of themselves*, then $S$ an element of itself'.

> 'S is a set of all sets that are not elements of themselves" is both the hypothesis and the statement. Kevin Houston, page 64:
>
> "Statement A is called the hyothesis or assumption" - Susanna S. Epp, page 390: "Euclidean Algorithm 1. Let A and B be integers with $A≥B≥0$."...recall that we assumed $A≥B≥0$

[image]

Comment: Other than creating broken CSS, eyestrain and the feeling that I'm looking at a drawing of a child, what point is there to the colors?

Comment: @AsafKaragila The colors are there for increasing the readability of my question. :)  By the way, what does CSS mean?

Comment: Cascaded Style Sheets. The design of the website. Currently broken, courtesy of the colored text overflowing from the question box.

Comment: @buzzee What is the point of pasting page 43 of your textbook?

Comment: @5xum I compared it with answers.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I removed the colors.

Comment: In general, why do you think that if a statement leads to a contradiction, then the statement (by reductio) holds true ? It is the opposite: [reductio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum) licenses to demonstrate that a statement is true deriving a contradiction from the **denial** of the statement to be proved.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA "One kind of indirect proof, argument by contradiction, is based on the fact that either a statement
is true or it is false but not both. So if you can show that the assumption that a given statement is not true leads logically to a contradiction, impossibility, or absurdity, then that assumption must be false: and, hence, the given statement must be true. This method of proof is also known as reductio ad impossible or reductio ad absurdum."
(Susanna S. Epp, page 198)

Comment: In any case, we have to "reverse" the truth-value of the assumption. In the specific case under discussion, the assumption: "there exists a set $S$ ..." leads to a contradiction; thus, by *reductio* we have to conclude that "does **not** exist a set $S$ ...".

Comment: You may check on as many texbook as you want, but Russell's proof (1901) is still correct after 115 years...

Comment: Formatting choices do not have to be "all or nothing". There is also a middle ground, which is both readable, and reasonable.

Comment: Paradox is when a statement is **both** provable and refutable.  So of course you can prove the statement by contraction and reducio and other methods.  You can also disprove it using those methods.  That is the point.

Answer (score 6):

NO: the statement

> "there exists the set $S$ of all sets that are not elements of themselves"

has been proved to be *false*.

The "logical analysis" of [Russell's Paradox](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/russell-paradox/) starts from the seemingly harmless principle [called: *unrestricted Comprehension Axiom*] that:

> for any formula $φ(x)$ containing $x$ as a free variable, there will exist the set $\{ x \mid φ(x) \}$.

Russell manufactured his paradox considering as $\varphi$ the *predicate* : $\lnot (x \in x)$.

Thus, according to the above principle, we are licensed to make the assumption:

> $\exists S \ \forall x \ (x \in S \leftrightarrow \lnot (x \in x))$ --- **(*)**

Applying inference rules, and instantiating the universal quantifier with $S$ we get:

> > $S \in S \leftrightarrow \lnot (S \in S)$.

This is **the** *contradiction*.

Thus, applying *reductio* to the initial assumption **(*)**, we conclude with:

> $\lnot \exists S \ \forall x \ (x \in S \leftrightarrow \lnot (x \in x))$.

And so we have to conclude that the *unrestricted Comprehension Axiom* is not a "sound" principle: we have to leave it, or to "restrict" in a suitable way its application.

See [Axiom schema of specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification) for a way to "fix" it.

Answer (score 4):

You're misreading the structure of the argument. The structure is:

- Suppose $S$ has the property $\forall x(x \in S \iff x \notin x)$.
- Then $S \in S \iff S \notin S$, a contradiction.
- Therefore, the assumption that $S$ has the property $\forall x(x \in S \iff x \notin x)$ was absurd.
- In other words, no set $S$ has the property $\forall x(x \in S \iff x \notin x).$
- Symbolically:

$$\forall S( \neg \forall x(x \in S \iff x \notin x))$$

Comment: I have tried putting it as "It is illogical to claim that there exists a widget that doodles all those and only those widgets that do not doodle themselves."