# Naive set theory as a first order theory

Tags: logic, reference-request, paradoxes

In the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox#Formal_presentation) about Russell's paradox the authors present the naive set theory as a [first order theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) (as far as I understand), but without references. Can anybody share some references where the naive set theory is presented that way (for explaining Russell's paradox) so that we could input them into the [Russian Wikipedia article](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81_%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0)?

Comment: You can see [Russell's Paradox](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/russell-paradox/).

Comment: And, of course, [Russell's letter to Frege](https://books.google.it/books?id=v4tBTBlU05sC&pg=PA125) (1902).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I need a reference where the naive set theory is presented as a  theory in the language of the first order logic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic

Comment: Naive set theory, in  modern terms, is simply, f-o logic with the [Unrestricted comprehension axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification#Unrestricted_comprehension): with it, R's Paradox follows.

Comment: See e.g. Patrick Suppes, [Axiomatic set theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=skTCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA5) (1960), page 5.

Comment: You can see also this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805431/doesnt-statement-s-is-a-set-of-all-sets-that-are-not-elements-of-themselves).

Comment: Mauro, I used to think this as well: "Naive set theory, in modern terms, is simply, f-o logic with the Unrestricted comprehension axiom". But in Wikipedia everything is very complicated, they insist on direct references. I see that Patrick Suppes doesn't use the words "first order logic"...

Comment: Suppes uses [quantification logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) aka predicate logic aka first-order logic.

Comment: As far as I can see, he doesn't say this directly. That is bad for a reference in Wikipedia.

Comment: I haven't read it in full, but knowing Azriel Levy in person, I'd imagine that his book Basic Set Theory should cover this quite thoroughly. Another option is Enderton's book which may be a better alternative to Suppes in this case. Also Halbeisen's "Combinatorial Set Theory" might have the necessary background for all this.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov: Many Wikipedia articles in mathematics do not quote their sources exactly, and is better off not doing so. Clearly notation is one aspect, since an article can't possibly keep changing notation. If it is clear to the target audience that two notions are equivalent, I don't see any reason for avoiding the use of more standard terminology.

Comment: @user21820, people, who write in Wikipedia, are very different. In Russian Wikipedia, for example, I did not find mathematicians specialised in logic at all. I have to presuade people that what I say is true, but I can't do this without references. You know, of course, the rules of Wikipedia are complicated, misty and contradictory, they provoke pemanent struggle between authors, but this concrete one - finding direct references - is, I believe, inevitable.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, you know, I can't find what I need in the books you mention.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov: I see. Well I gave up on Wikipedia quite a long time ago for everything else except mathematical articles, which seem to be written largely by mathematically trained people who don't really care about the silly rules as compared to being mathematically correct, but I've only seen the English ones so I had no idea it was much different from the Russian ones.

Comment: @Sergei: I don't know what you're looking for exactly, but Levy does cover the paradox and the fact that it is in fact just a first-order logic validity: $\lnot\exists y\forall x(x\in y\leftrightarrow x\notin x)$, whenever $\in$ is a binary relation symbol.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I need a definition of naive set theory in the language a first order logic. For example, Patrick Suppes is close to this on page 5: "almost all of the theorems... can be derived from three axioms: (i)... (ii)... (iii)..." - but he does not write directly that "naive set theory can be defined as a first order theory with the following axioms..." The problem is that I am arguing with non-specialists, it's impossible to explain them anything without direct  references.

Comment: Sergei, there is no concrete definition of naive set theory. Some people consider naive set theory to be what the 19th century had to offer; others would tell you that naive set theory is just ZFC without regularity; and others will argue otherwise that the theory is not even given in terms of axioms and logic. So yeah, you're between a rock and a hard place. Good luck.

Comment: Eh!... I expected that there are some common opinions. We could write something like this: "according to [1], [2], [3], naive set theory can be defined as the first order theory with equality $=$, binary prediacte symbol $\in$ and the following axioms: extensionality, unrestricted comprehension, etc." OK, Asaf, thank you! If somebody will find at least one reference, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Let me ask you this, then, what makes naive set theory naive?

Comment: Asaf, some things loose their charm after formal definition. I thought this is the case. :)

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov: What you've just stated is indeed common opinion. Technically, in the case of Russell's paradox one could say that the historical fact is that the naive set theory in question was Frege's logic, which Frege himself acknowledged was inconsistent after seeing the paradox. Also you may be interested in "Is ZF a hack?" (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1570868305000765), which basically says that from a type theory viewpoint ZF arises from the single assumption that $set = set \to bool$, which is of course inconsistent in any reasonable system.

Comment: My experience matches Asaf's comment: there is no standard definition of "naive set theory". Besides the question of whether naive set theory is formalized at all, or just an informal set of natural-language axioms, some authors refer to an inconsistent set theory as 'naive set theory' while others refer to a consistent theory. Personally, I think that if you make the comprehension axiom into an explicit first-order axiom scheme, you are not in the realm of naive set theory any more (so "naive" = "not fully formalized"). But others use "naive" to indicate an unrestricted comprehension axiom.

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard definition of "naive set theory". I am going to make this a community wiki answer in which people can record various definitions.

Some definitions of "naive set theory" include:

- Informal systems of set theory that are not stated in any formal logic. In such system the comprehension refers informally to "properties" but is not stated as an axiom scheme. Depending on the author, these may have a restricted comprehension axiom, and thus be intended to be consistent, or may have an unrestricted comprehension axiom, and thus be intended to be inconsistent.
- Formal systems of set theory with unrestricted comprehension (which may thus be inconsistent).
- Halmos' book *Naive Set Theory* has its own sense of "naive" which is quoted below.

#### Halmos' *Naive Set Theory*

The following quotes are from the preface of Halmos' *Naive Set Theory*.

> The purpose of this book is to tell the beginning student of advanced mathematics the basic set-theoretic facts of life, and to do so with the minimum of philosophical discourse and logical formalism. (p. v)

> In set theory "naive" and "axiomatic" are contrasting words. The present treatment might best be described as axiomatic set theory from the naive point of view. It is axiomatic in that some axioms for set theory are stated and used as the basis of all subsequent proofs. It is naive in that the language and notation are those of ordinary informal (but formalizable) mathematics. A more important way in which the naive point of view predominates is that set theory is regarded as a body of facts, of which the axioms are a brief and convenient; in the orthodox axiomatic view the logical relations among various axioms are the central object of study. Analogously, a study of geometry might be regarded as naive if it proceeded on the paper-folding kind of intuition along; the other extreme, the purely axiomatic one, is the one in which axioms for the various non-Euclidean geometries are studied with the same amount of attention as Euclid's. The analogue of the point of view of this book is the study of just one sane set of axioms with the intention of describing Euclidean geometry only. (pp. v-vi).

Halmos briefly sketches the syntax of first-order logic in order to state the "Axiom of Specification", so it could be argued that his axiom is intended to be a scheme in first-order logic.